# How to use "adjustResize" to adjust view in Android using phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, keyboard, window-soft-input-mode

We can set `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"` to adjust screen view while user click on Edit Text Field.

I want to do same thing in HTML form. While user click on Textbox then view should be automatically adjust so user can type easily ans along with that they can see what they are typing exactly.

See the difference

[image]
[image]

How can i do same thing in android using Phone Gap.I hope you will guide me in right way.

Thank you for read my query.

Comment: hello friend. have you solved this problem?

Comment: could you show the not perfect way? may be we can sort it out together. thanks

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11300/phonegap-framework @dimaninc come here will discuss :)

Comment: @chintan khetiya: It's helpful to document solutions here where others can benefit from them. :)

Comment: Any resolution to this?

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to change the target-densitydpi on the viewport to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
```

Hope it helps